# What is the creative device naming used for text generation in Pelevin's S.N.U.F.F.?

Tags: russian-language, translation, victor-pelevin, s-n-u-f-f

What is the proper, **published**, translation in the only AFAIK existing English version of the book S.N.U.F.F. by Victor Pelevin?

> Grim uploaded the germ of his perplexity and sadness in the *creative
>   unit*, touched axes "heartier", "sincerier" and then the sub-axis
>   "salinger", which popped in the terminal sectors of the intimate
>   afterburner.
>
> (...)
>
> This software takes into consideration everything ever said by humans, all the countless choice of meanings they made during centuries as were retained in information archives. It was as if Grim's fingers controlled an army of dead souls, who would move word cubicles for him.

(found about somewhere about the beginning of the last fifth of the book; but Pelevin mentions this device many times throughout the book).

Side note: while back in 2012 this device seemed a total fiction, today [there are recent scientific methods](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/24878/gans-possible-for-text-as-well) indeed allowing generating meaningful texts *with a design to perfect this routines*.

Comment: Could you indicate approximately where in the book this quote appears (e.g. chapter number at least, page number if possible)? Would make it easier for people to track down the quote for translation.

Comment: thank you @Randal'Thor; this device is an important concept in the book and is referenced many times; following your advice, I did my best to point out the place of this specific and as appears to me most prominent quote.

Comment: *Heartier, sincerer, and salinger* is clearly one of those coincidences that happen in translation. I first took it to mean *more hearty, more sincere, and more saling*.

Comment: a nice one; but still, and  therefore, I am really eager to find out the "official" version

Comment: You are talking about the English word used in the Bromfield translation?

Comment: @SAH yes, exactly